Why nested if run faster?
I found the nested if run faster than serialized if and it confused me.
I have a code that needs to be run 100 million times:
if(b8 < 254) {
    if(b8 < 252)
        return data[b8];
    return random_bit() ? data[b8] : -data[b8];
}

The b8 is an uint8_t random number and random_bit() returns a 0-1 random number. This fragment will return some value with 2 if-judgments and I realized I could rewrite it as
if(b8 < 252)
    return data[b8];
if(b8 < 254)
    return random_bit() ? data[b8] : -data[b8];

Now, return data[b8] only needs 1 if-judgement. However, I noticed that the program slowed down by about 0.01s with 100 million repetitions. For some reason I need this code to run faster, even if it's 0.01s. So did I misunderstand anything about this code?
BTW, the code is compiled with -Ofast and the assembly code is too complex to understand for me. The assembly code:
.L2:    ; nested
    cmpb    $-3, %bl
    ja  .L3
    movzbl  %bl, %r12d
    cmpb    $-5, %bl
    ja  .L4
    movsbl  sample_val.8(%r12), %ebx
    addq    $8, %rsp
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r13
    ret

.L2:    ; serialized
    cmpb    $-5, %r14b
    jbe .L24
    movl    %r14d, %ebx                 ; inline random_bit()
    movl    $8, %r12d
    movq    cnt.7(%rip), %rdx
    movabsq $4611686018427387904, %r13
    andl    $1, %ebx
    cmpb    $-3, %r14b
    ja  .L19
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .L6
    shrq    %rdx
    movq    b64.6(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rdx, cnt.7(%rip)

GCC just compiles them to different things though I think they are equivalent.

The compiler can make the same inference that you're making yourself as a human. I wouldn't expect the number of actual conditional branches to be tightly bound to the shape of your code.

How exactly did you benchmark it and what exactly were the results? Even if you didn’t understand the disassembly, did you verify that they compiled to different things? I’d think that this one should be pretty easy for the compiler, and would expect them to compile to the same instructions.

Your two code-snippets does slightly different things, they are not 100% equivalent.

@Someprogrammerdude: Is this accounting for b8 being a non-integer type, or are you referring to something else?

I add the assembly, they are different things. Maybe I should just use nested code without knowing why :(

It really depends on what values of b8 are most common.  The code distinguishes three cases:

b8 < 252
252 <= b8 < 254
b8 >= 254

Now consider the number of comparisons the two versions do for each of these cases.
The "nested" code does (1) 2 comparisons (2) 2 comparisons (3) 1 comparison.
The "serialized" code does (1) 1 comparison (2) 2 comparisons (3) 2 comparisons.
So the "nested" code optimizes the case where b8 >= 254, while the "serialized" code optimizes the case where b8 < 252.
